# Unable to publish to SNS Topic from Lambda inside private subnet of VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I have a lambda function, which requires access to EC2 running on the private subnet of my VPC. So I associated the lambda with private subnet of the VPC. My lambda also need to publish to an SNS Topic. I have even configured SNS VPC Interface Endpoint for SNS access. But I cant publish to an SNS from this lambda. What am I doing wrong? Here is my configuration.

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "sns" {
  vpc_id              = VPC_ID
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.ca-central-1.sns"
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  private_dns_enabled = true
  subnet_ids = [
    PRIVATE_SUBNET_ID
  ]
  security_group_ids = [
    SECURITY_GROUP_FOR_PRIVATE_EC2_ID
  ]
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip" {
  domain = "vpc"
  tags = {
    Name = "TAG"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.db_proxy]
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "db_proxy" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_eip.id
  subnet_id     = PUBLIC_SUBNET_ID

  tags = {
    Name = "TAG"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.db_proxy]
}

# Route Table associated with Private Subnet
resource "aws_route_table" "db_proxy_private" {
  vpc_id = VPC_ID

  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.db_proxy.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "TAG"
  }
}

# Security group associated with Private EC2.
resource "aws_security_group" "db_proxy_sg_private" {
  name        = NAME
  description = "Managed by Terraform"
  vpc_id      = VPC_ID

  # To Allow SSH Transport
  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"] // Public Subnet CIDR
    description = "Whitelisted SSH IPs"
  }

  # To Allow Port 80 Transport
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = 80
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"] // Public Subnet CIDR
    description = "Outgoing HTTP transport"
  }

  # Open port 8000 for external access
  ingress {
    from_port   = 8000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = 8000
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24"] // Public Subnet CIDR
    description = "EC2 HTTP port"
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Assuming Lambda has been successfully associated with private subnet and private security group. Lambda config not attached here.

My SNS call times out when lambda is associated with private subnet. When dissociated, it works as expected. Im assuming something wrong with configuring SNS VPC Interface Endpoint.

Comment: What security group are you assigning to the Lambda function? Is it the same security group you included in your question that you are using for an EC2 instance? The Terraform code in your question is missing a lot of details, like the Lambda function and the actual VPC Subnet.

Comment: Yes, Im using the above mentioned security group for lambda as well as SNS Endpoint.

Comment: **NOTE:** `[10.0.1.0/24]` is my public subnet CIDR & `[10.0.2.0/24]` is my private subnet CIDR. Currently, the above mentioned security group allows SSH, port 80, port 8000 from public subnet.

Comment: Also to note, `[10.0.0.0/16]` is my VPC CIDR.

Comment: I have resolved SNS Endpoint issue, by attaching a security group to allow all TCP traffic from `0.0.0.0/0`. Now able to publish from lambda inside private subnet :)

Comment: Your issue was you weren't allowing port `443` inbound connections in the security group attached to the SNS endpoint. It's really bad practice to use a single security group for multiple resources of completely different types.  You should have a security group for your Lambda, another for your EC2, and another for your SNS endpoint, each with the correct rules for that specific resource.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, Lambda function is missing IAM permissions. A Lambda function in VPC needs the following permissions to work properly.

#### Execution role permissions

- `ec2:CreateNetworkInterface`
- `ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces`
- `ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface`

These permissions are included in the AWS managed policy **AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole**.

So, make sure the IAM Role for the Lambda function has this managed policy attached.

Comment: Missing IAM permissions do not result in a timeout, they result in a permission denied error.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with @MarkB. I have already configured IAM permissions to create Network Interface. Im having timeout issue, which I suspect something to do with security group associated with SNS VPC Interface Endpoint.